# How to know when a Runtime.exec() process is stuck, programatically?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am executing some pl/sql file using `Process` in unix server. Below is the code

```
String line;
Process p = null;

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sqlplus -s " + USER + "/" + PASS + "@" + sid + " @" + sqlTempDirectory);

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("invalid username/password")) {
            System.out.println(sql.getName() + " file creation skipped as invalid username/password");
            p.destroy();
            break;
        }
}
input.close();
```

**Problem :** This `java.lang.Process` sometimes get struck due to invalid username/password, file not found or may be some unknown exception.Right now, based on the input stream data I'm catching the exception and destroying the process using `p.destroy().` But this only covers the exception I'm aware of, not any other exception that may occur.

**Question :** How can I know for sure whether the process is struck or not? If it is struck then I want to destroy the `java.lang.Process`.

**Edit** Checking the activity of the thread might not be solution as in my case I'm connecting to database. So the process might wait for database connectivity and resume if the connection is setup that might take time. I'm running the code in a live server instance so waiting can occur. This does not proof that the process is dead. I want to be sure when the process is deadlock and won't resume anytime in future.

**Edit 2 :** I don't want to kill entire java program execution. I just want to destroy that particular `java.lang.Process`. So the solution has to be some java code which will destroy the `java.lang.Process` and move on with rest of the program.

**Edit 3:** The question is not duplicate as I need a Java way. Getting thread dump won't help. I just want to **destroy `java.lang.Process`** , not the complete java program execution.

**Main Question: When should I kill my Process.**

**Not how, but when.** I dont want to apply timeout as I'll run the program in some live instance and there might be many other external reason for the process to stuck and the process might have a chance to resume. But in case of exception the process wont resume. I want to handle those scenarios.
The input streams are empty so dont know whether error occured or not.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: @DannyChen it does not answer my question. I have sepecific sql files. So keeping check on that thread to see activity might not be helpful. May be the process is waiting for database connection and might resume after sometime. So killing a process based on time is not a solution. I want to be sure that the process is deadlock and wont execute further.

Comment: There is no evidence of a deadlock here. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @EJP ok sorry for the confusion... But still the question is not answered how would I know whether the process will result into something or stay as it is in case of exception mentioned. I'm facing this issue as after executing the process nothing is happening for hours. Even the input stream is empty. I dont want to apply timeout as I'll run the program in some live instance and there might be many other external reason for the process to stuck and the process might have a chance to resume. But in case of exception the process wont resume. I want to handle those scenarios

Comment: If your real question is " I just want to destroy java.lang.Process , not the complete java program execution", please submit that question separately.

Comment: @Arkadiy I don't understand the difference. To destroy the `java.lang.Process`, I should know when it is stuck. Based on that I want to take the decision of destroying it. So how posting a different question, which should give me the same answer help?  If you think the title is misleading based on what I want, please help me in correcting it.

Comment: Question one: how do I know when the process is stuck? Question 2: how do I kill a process? Question 1 is a duplicate. Question 2 may not be..

Comment: @Arkadiy The latter question is edit after my duplicate close vote. i've already voted for reopen.

Comment: @Arkadiy The question whose duplicate this question is mentioned to be gives the solution from OS perspective. One can see the progress using Java Dump and kill the complete program externally. I want a Java way. In my complete program, this `java.lang.Process` is a very small part, so if in case it is stuck I would just like to destroy it inside my code and move on with rest of the code. Also I know how to kill it but not when to kill it. I want to know when to kill it.

Comment: @HarshitaSethi from a theoretical perspective to determine wether an arbitrary given program will come to an end is known as the "halting problem" and it is proven that there is no algorithm that can decide this. I your special case only you know what the problem is meant to do and whether you can check if it is making any progress, so only you can tell if there is a way to tell whether the program is stuck.

Comment: Definition of  "stuck" is usecase dependent. In your case, have a time based check to see the state of process (`isAlive()`) and take action: `destroy` and `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean stuck ? A stuck thread is observed via jvm monitoring tools like jconsole. If you want to stop the os process based on some exception and/or run time Error , you can simply wrap your code in catch block

```
try {
        //process initiation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //attempt process stop
    }catch(Error ex){
        //attempt process stop
    }
```

Starting an operating system process is highly system-dependent. In case you want to attempt to stop the os process if it takes longer than you expect, you can start the process in a thread with for which you can specify timeout.

Comment: Stuck mean I execute a file using `Runtime.exec()` and it does not do anything. It gets blocked due to some reason.. The reason is not visible to me. There is no exception but the process is blocked, its a deadlock.

Comment: @HarshitaSethi A block is not a deadlock. It is a block. A deadlock is where there are two processes and two locks (or more). This is a block. Don't misuse standard terminology.